# Merging cells of an Excel spreadsheet using Java

Tags: java, excel

I'm working on an application that needs to get values from a database and write them in an Excel sheet.

The values in the first column are to be repeated, so I want to merge the first column's cells to display unique values.

For example, if the first five cells in the first column contain the value `EMPLOYEE`, instead of displaying "employee" five times, I want to display only one "employee" in a cell created by a merge of the original five cells.

Answer (score 0):

Place all your information in your collection of choice, sort on the first column value.

So now you will have something like this:

```
Employee  Ben      Canhaveasurname
Employee  Sarah    HasASurname
Employee  Collin   NoSurname
```

What you can do now, is loop through the collection, keeping track of column 1 in a local variable, if it changes, write it out, otherwise, skip it.  Start with an empty String so you get the first change.